# Access to node's process.env variables in a package?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, node-modules

If I have `project A` that is used as an npm package in `project B`. If I set my env variables in `project B` on startup (say for `process.env.production`), is the environment variable accessible in `project A`?

Comment: Simple as that, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: YES.

Detailed answer :

- you should install dotenv package,
- Add : `<< import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'; dotenv.config(); >>` to your entry point et "Voilà".

Comment: I tried this method but my browser throws an error : "process is not defined"